# difference in data storage between type and class

Tags: fortran

In the following example, the intrinsic function `transfer()` works well for 'b'.

But it does not work for polymorphic object `a` (i.e. can not return char array of correct size).

Could anyone explain the reason of this?

And could anyone provide any idea in serializing/packaging data of arbitrary type (for use of MPI)?

Thanks.

```
module mm
  type::typeA
    integer dat(10)
  end type
end module

program test
  use mm
  class(typeA),allocatable::a
  type(typeA)::b
  allocate(a)
  write(*,*),size(transfer(a,['c']))
  write(*,*),size(transfer(b,['c']))
end program
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The polymorphic object most likely contains additional hidden fields such as a pointer to the class vtable and/or RTTI table. Additionally, as you've made the polymorphic object allocatable, there might be additional hidden fields due to that.

As the vtable addresses are not guaranteed to be the same on different MPI ranks, transferring those pointer values is unlikely to be useful. Instead, for a polymorphic type you must create custom serializing/deserializing routines, where you serialize each data field, transfer it to another MPI rank, and at the receiving end you create an empty object and fill it in with the data received.